# How can I import "wav" file like "RecordSound"

Tags: sound

How to import [audio file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk4vovvjcpngm4k/My%20recording%20%232.wav?dl=0) like as `"SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]"`?

```
tako = Import["C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kk\\My recording #2.wav"]
```

[image]

```
tako // InputForm // Short
```

[image]

but if I use `SystemDialogInput[]`

```
SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]
```

[image]

```
rec // InputForm // Short
```

[image]

I need `InputForm` like `rec // InputForm // Short`

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question and make it clearer: you are asking how to get a `Sound` expression instead of an `Audio` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WAV.html) `"Sound"` element instead of the default `"Audio"` element.

```
Import[..., {"WAV", "Sound"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Audio to Sound:

```
a = Audio[File["ExampleData/car.mp3"]];
Sound[SampledSoundList[AudioData@#, QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate@#]]&@a
```

Sound to Audio:

```
sound = Sound[{SoundNote["C"], SoundNote["G"]}];
Audio@sound
```